# Vue JS: Save the value of a prop in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

How do I save the value of a dynamic prop? The values of the prop change dynamically, but I want to work with the first value the component receives by the prop. So it's basically like the prop was only send once to the component. How do I achieve this and how is it done in Vuex?

Comment: Maybe create a variable with `initialState` and save this first value the component receives by the prop ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use Vuex for this. Inside your component, you could have a variable that receives the prop value on create.

```js
export default {
  props: ['propCount'],
  data() {
    compCount: 0
  },
  created() {
    this.compCount = this.propCount
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but now I see I used the wrong lifecycle hook. This works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest saving the initial value of the prop in another variable

```
{
    props: {
        myProp: String
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
             initialPropValue: null
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.initialPropValue = this.myProp;
    }
}
```

If you want to save your value to vuex, add a state variable and a mutation there:

```
{
    state: {
        initialPropValue: null
    },
    mutations: {
        setInitialPropValue(state, value){
             state.initialPropValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, change your created method to:

```
created() {
     this.$store.commit("setInitialPropValue", this.myProp);
}
```